# Как отключить уведомления о действиях пользователей на сайте wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как отключить уведомления на почту администратора сайта о действиях зарегистрированных пользователей?
к примеру пользователь поменял пароль, об этом приходит уведомление на почту.
Как это уведомление отключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Этот фильтр вставить в файл functions.php Вашей темы

Comment: подскажите, а как сделать, чтобы эти сообщения приходили на другую почту? т.е. на дополнительную почту, чтобы не засорять спамом основную?